# « Combien », « comment », « à quel point », « comme »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

En parlant de la croissance d’un jeune animal, de l’évolution, de jour en jour, de son poids.

J’ai hâte de voir

…combien le chiot a grandi.

…comment le chiot a grandi.

…à quel point le chiot a grandi.

…comme le chiot a grandi.

Autre formulation?

—————

D’autres idées qui me viennent en tête.

J’ai hâte de voir l’évolution de la croissance du chiot.

J’ai hâte de voir où en est la croissance du chiot.

Comment: Toutes les propositions sont valides mais ont un sens qui peut légèrement différer... difficile de répondre sans connaître l'intention du locuteur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une phrase à  propos  d'une  différence de taille (quantité) ne peut être formulée que par « combien » et « à quel point ». « Comme » et « comment » ne porte que sur la manière,« Comme » servant en plus à intensifier.

- J'ai hâte de voir combien le  chiot a grandi.
- J'ai hâte de voir à quel point le  chiot a grandi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme)) **comme**
> **I.**  − Adv. exclam.
> **A.** − Exclam. en constr. dir.
> **1.** L'alternance comme/que est possible. Comme est un adv. exclam. d'intensité.
> • Mais comme vous êtes enrhumé, De Berville! Flers, Caillavet, M. Brotonneau,1923, I, 9, p. 6.
> **B.** − Intensité en constr. indir.
> **1.** L'alternance comme/combien est possible. Comme est un adv. exclam. d'intensité.
> • Tu ne sauras jamais comme j'ai été malheureuse (Maupassant, Une Vie,1883, p. 242).

« Comme » et « combien » servent à donner de l'intensité à  la constatation de l'augmentation de taille (ou à la constatation d'autres choses). « Comment » ne convient pas pour ça, mais  « à quel point » est utilisé (sauf en constructions directes).

- Comme/Combien le chiot a grandi !
- Je n'en revenait pas comme/combien le chiot avait grandi.
- Tu ne peux pas savoir à quel point je suis heureuse de te voir ! ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_hymne_%C3%A0_la_joie/hcE5EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A0+quel+point%22&pg=PT24&printsec=frontcover))
- Tu ne peux pas savoir comme/combien je suis heureuse de te voir !
- <s>À quel point  je suis heureuse de te voir !</s>
- Comme la neige est lumineuse dans le soleil ! (*constatations exclamatives d'autres choses, évidemment*)

> J’ai hâte de voir l’évolution de la croissance du chiot.

L'évolution de la croissance présuppose une soigneuse observation en référence à des critères assez bien établis, bien que pas nécessairement des plus techniques, sur une période assez longue durant la croissance; ce n'est pas le contexte propre aux personnes   qui  occasionnellement vont s'informer de la croissance à moins qu'elles aient elles-mêmes quelques aptitudes de spécialiste, un intérêt particulier pour un sujet plutôt technique.

> J’ai hâte de voir où en est la croissance du chiot.

Cette forme-ci semble convenir aux contextes courants.